# What mechanism does Firefox use to remember the in-session logins, after entering the Master Password?

Tags: web-browser, firefox

After I have entered my Master Password, does Firefox decrypt all the logins and store them somewhere? Or does it store the Master Password itself? Is the in-session period (more) vulnerable to attack?

Answer (score 1):

The password database isn't encrypted directly with your master password, instead a hash of the master password is computed and that hash is used to encrypt/decrypt the password database.

After you typed your master password, Firefox doesn't store the plaintext password anymore and instead simply use the hashed password to access the file.

Comment: After entering my password the following files changed: webappstore.sqlite, webappstore.sqlite-wal, sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4. I guess it is possible the hashed password is kept in one of those, or in RAM. Would you say the latter to be more secure (harder to access)?

Comment: I think I understood wrongly. You say the hash is *already* in the file system, and that is used to decrypt the logins? If so, that doesn't seem to be secure at all...

Comment: @Stockos if you set a master password, the password hash is not stored in the filesystem. It's recomputed everytime you open the password database.